# User import to Joomla from CSV file

Tags: database, csv, joomla, import

Sorry for probably duplication but I am not technically minded so I do not understand most of the other posts.

I used to have a website hosted by Spruz - I have exported the user data in CSV files. I want to import this data into my Joomla site (hosted by 1and1) so users of the old ste can log in to the new one without signing up again - I have contacted 1and1 multiple times but I haven't got a helpful answer yet.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35052511/1983389

Answer (score 0):

If you are not technically minded, then you are going to have to use a third party extension to do this.  There are a few here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export

Make sure your csv matches the format they require.

If you want to do it manually with a database query, then the users table is where most of the data is stored, but check out what all the other tables starting user_ are saving when a user is created, as you may need to link their id to their usergroup or profile.

http://docs.joomla.org/Tables

(Unless they built your site, then it is very unlikely that web hosts will help with any questions about the website's content.  You may need to hire a developer to help you if you get really stuck.)