# Import Users from CSV / Excel file in Joomla 3

Tags: csv, import, joomla3.2

I need to create about 100 users in a Joomla 3.2 system. Is there a way to do this automatically and without high costs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joomla! - Import users from CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208376/joomla-import-users-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best component for this is this:

CSV Improved: http://www.csvimproved.com/

But you can try this component aswell:

J-Import: http://mycircletree.com/products/joomla-and-jomsocial-user-creation-data-import-component/

Answer (score 2):

There is a very inexpensive extension called [IMPORT/UPLOAD USERS INTO JOOMLA 
(+User Profile) FROM EXCEL OR CSV FILE](https://www.ukrsolution.com/Joomla/Import-Joomla-Users-From-Excel-CSV-File) which can easily handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

CSV Improved is only free up to Joomla 2.5.

The recently released "Users Importer for J2XML" is free and enables you to import users from a CSV file:

http://extensions.joomla.org/browse/new/extension/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export/users-importer-for-j2xml